# How to get a function's default parameter in python?

Tags: python

`from imapclient import IMAPClient`

I use imapclient module, the function
`IMAPClient.fetch(self, messages, data,modifiers=None)`.

`data` should be specified as a sequnce of strings, one item per data selector, for example `['INTERNALDATE', 'RFC822']`.

I want to know what are other default parameters besides `INTERNALDATE` and `RFC822`.

I will be appreciate if you tell me how to get them when use other functions.

Comment: You want to get other parameters besides `data`, or other parameters in `data` besides `InTERNALDATE` and `RFC822` ?

Comment: I would strongly recommend reading http://imapclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I want to know other parameters in *data* besides *INTERNALDATE* and *RFC822*, I've already read http://imapclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/, I cannot find the answer, sorry! Can you help me?

Comment: @user2901573 Could you please read IMAP RFC (http://james.apache.org/server/rfclist/imap4/rfc2060.txt)? Check `6.4.5.  FETCH Command`. It lists the currently defined data items that can be fetched.

Comment: @lhuang Thanks, I've found it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`IMAPClient.fetch` is for **FETCH Command** in IMAP. So you can get can get defined data selectors in IMAP RFC, part **6.4.5. FETCH Command**.

[INTERNET MESSAGE ACCESS PROTOCOL - VERSION 4rev1](http://james.apache.org/server/rfclist/imap4/rfc2060.txt)